# How to fix api json delete request

Tags: json, laravel, unit-testing

In following code, I'm trying to create a new category (name = 'To be deleted') and then I want to delete it.

first part of the code working fine and I can see new record in the database every time I run the unit test

but I'm having a problem with recode deletion. what's wrong with my code

```
public function testCategoryDeletion()
{
    $user = \App\User::find(1);
    //dd($user->name);
    $category = \App\Category::create(['name' => 'To be deleted']);
    //dd($category->id);
    $response = $this->actingAs($user, 'api')
        ->json('DELETE', "/api/category/{$category->id}")
        ->assertStatus(200)->assertJson([
            'status'  => true,
            'message' => 'Category Deleted',
        ]);
}
```

Test case output

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\Chathura\Vue_Laravel_API> ./vendor/bin/phpunit
PHPUnit 7.5.7 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.    .    .    .    .    .    .                                                             7 / 7 (100%)

Time: 1.53 minutes, Memory: 18.00 MB

OK (7 tests, 65 assertions)
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\Chathura\Vue_Laravel_API>
```

In database, recode is created but not deleted,

[image: database]

Comment: what is error? can you post that also?

Comment: there is no error, I have updated question please take a look

Comment: Can you share the related delete method also, may be you returned the array but not deleted it actually?

Comment: Please can you show the controller method and route for the delete route `/api/category/{category}`?

Comment: There was an issue with delete method in the controller, I found it and now its working. thank you guys.

Comment: If you've found your issue please may you either add the solution as an answer to your question or just delete the question altogether :)

Comment: I added the answer with API routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the controller as follows and now its working,

```
public function destroy(Category $category)
{

    $status  = $category->delete();

    return response()->json([
        'status' => $status,
        'message' => $status ? 'Category Deleted' : 'Error Deleting Category'
    ]);

}
```

API routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
        Route::resource('/task', 'TaskController');
        Route::resource('/category', 'CategoryController');
        Route::get('/category/{category}/tasks', 'CategoryController@tasks');
    });
```